# Remover un fila de mi gridview ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

como puedo remover un row de mi gridview en asp.net una vez que selecciono un registro, sin que afecte la base de datos, es decir la lista figura en memoria.

Este es el código como cargo mi GriewView:

```
    private void Cargar()
    {
        srvLeyenda = new Srv_Leyenda();
        GridView1.DataSource = null;
        listadoLeyendas= srvLeyenda.LeerLeyendas();

        GridView1.DataSource = listadoLeyendas;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Sólo por curiosidad, ¿por qué quieres hacer eso?

Comment: Hola, mi idea es selecionar un row del gridview y pasar ese dato a textbox para modificarlo. Una vez que termina de seleccionar todos los row de la grilla se persisten todos los datos. Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

Los elementos del grid lo debes remover del origen de datos, en tu caso la lista que uses y debes conservar en memoria:

```
private void Cargar()
{
    var srvLeyenda = new Srv_Leyenda();
    var listadoLeyendas = srvLeyenda.LeerLeyendas();

    Session["leyendas"] = listadoLeyendas;

    GridView1.DataSource = listadoLeyendas;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}


private void Remover(int id)
{
    var listadoLeyendas = Session["leyendas"] as List<Leyenda>

    listadoLeyendas = listadoLeyendas.Where(x=>x.id != id).ToList();

    Session["leyendas"] = listadoLeyendas; //actualizas los datos luego de remover

    GridView1.DataSource = listadoLeyendas;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

como verás, cuando cargas el grid mantienes los datos en `Session` para después cuando vas eliminando la operación la realizas sobre esta lista sin ir a la base de datos.

Comment: Otra alternativa puede ser usando **ViewState.Add("listadoLeyendas", listadoLeyendas);**

Comment: Leandro, el codigo que me compartiste solo funciona cuando selecciono un solo item del gridview.  cuando seleccion otro item vuelve aparecer el primer elemento que elimine. Como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: no se que accion realizas cuando seleccionas un item, pero recuerda que despues de la carga inicial debes seguir usando los datos que dejaste en Session[], no debes ir a la db porque sino vuelves a recargar con los datos originales

Comment: me di cuenta que faltaba algo en el codigo, actualizar la Session despues de eliminar